# Scaling Y axis errorbars in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

HI all I'm using Rstudio with the following dataframe:

```
                      X NSUM MEAN LOWMEAN UPMEAN
2 Nonmonetary Incentive  800 4.86    4.58   5.15
3       $0 (no mention)  822 5.06    4.78   5.35
4                  $25   830 6.35    6.06   6.65
5                  $50   815 6.84    6.54   7.14
6                  $75   864 7.00    6.70   7.29
```

So I've created this nice plot using the following command:

```
plot1 <- ggplot(rawdata, aes(x = rawdata$X, y = rawdata$MEAN)) + 
  geom_point(colour = "red") + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = rawdata$LOWMEAN, ymax = rawdata$UPMEAN, width =0), colour = "black") + 
  coord_flip()
```

Which plots the means and a bar to show the upper and lower bounds. What I want to do is change the y axis so the ticks don't appear as often but no matter what I do, ylim() or scale_y_continuous() I get the error:

Discrete values applied to continuous variable?

Comment: You shouldn't use `$` inside ggplot. In the first argument you specify `rawdata` as your data, you don't have to keep re-typing it throughout.

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you could:

1. provide reproducible data rather than giving us the output and
2. show us what arguments you passed to `ylim()` and
   `scale_y_continuous()`. Without that, it's hard to know exactly what
   you did wrong since this is where your problem is. We can't fix it
   if we don't know that.

Something like `scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(4.5, 7.5, by = 1))` should work fine. This scales the axis (rawdata$MEAN) from 4.5 to 7.5 in increments of 1. You should be able to make the axis work fine this way. Something like `ylim(4.5, 7.5)` also works. When I added this to your ggplot code it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

So there are a couple of things.

First, `aes(...)` evaluates it's argument *in the context of the default dataset*. This means that `aes(x=X,...)` will look (first) for a column `X` in whatever data frame you use in the `data=...` argument (`rawdata`, in your case). You should *never* use, e.g. `rawdata$X` inside `aes(...)`. This can cause unpredictable and often very obscure results.

Second, to control the number of axis ticks, use `breaks=...` and `limits=...` in `scale_y_continuous(...)`. The former will set the ticks but might not display all of them because limits are set automatically. The latter will override the default limits. So here are two example with your data:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(rawdata, aes(x = X, y = MEAN)) + 
  geom_point(colour = "red") + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = LOWMEAN, ymax = UPMEAN, width =0)) + 
  coord_flip()+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(4,5,6,7,8))
```

[image]

Notice how we've set the breaks to (4,5,6,7,8), but we don't see 4 and 8. This is because `ggplot` is setting limits automatically, which don't include 4 and 8. You can force this as follows:

```
ggplot(rawdata, aes(x = X, y = MEAN)) + 
  geom_point(colour = "red") + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = LOWMEAN, ymax = UPMEAN, width =0)) + 
  coord_flip()+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(4,5,6,7,8), limits=c(4,8))
```

[image]

Finally, if you want toget rid of the faint grid lines *between* the major ticks, you need to use `theme(...)`

```
ggplot(rawdata, aes(x = X, y = MEAN)) + 
  geom_point(colour = "red") + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = LOWMEAN, ymax = UPMEAN, width =0)) + 
  coord_flip()+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(4,5,6,7,8), limits=c(4,8))+
  theme(panel.grid.minor=element_blank())
```

[image]