# How to fix the axis breaks in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

## Data

I have following plot:

[image]

It was created using following code:

```
ggplot(data=new.data, mapping=aes(x= m.speed*1.09728, y=m.gaptime)) + 
  geom_point(aes(shape=interaction(Vehicle.class,PrecVehClass)), size=3, fill="black") + 
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(1,25,12), name="Vehicle Following Case", 
                     labels = c("Car Following Car", "Truck Following Car", "Car Following Truck")) + 
  stat_smooth(aes(x= m.speed*1.09728, y=m.gaptime, linetype=interaction(Vehicle.class,PrecVehClass)),size=1,color="black",method="loess", alpha=0)  + 
  scale_linetype_manual(values=c("dotted", "solid", "longdash"), name="Vehicle Following Case",
                        labels = c("Car Following Car", "Truck Following Car", "Car Following Truck")) +
  scale_x_discrete(breaks=seq(5,90, by=5)) +
  labs(x='Mean Speed (Km/hr)', y='Mean Time Gap (s)') + 
  theme_bw() + my.theme()
```

## Question

You can see that the last tick mark on x axis (75) is at the boundary of plot and the first box on left doesn't contain any data. I tried different `limits` and `breaks` in `scale_discrete` as shown in code but can't fix this problem. Please help.

Comment: Can we have a reproducible example, please? I would use `scale_x_continuous`, though.

Comment: I your code you seem to be setting `breaks` but not `limits`. You need to set both. See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25066211/scaling-y-axis-errorbars-in-ggplot2/25097767#25097767).